# How can Linq be so incredibly fast? C#

Tags: linq, dictionary

Let's say I have 100 000 objects of type `Person` which have a date property with their birthday in them.

I place all the objects in a `List<Person>` (or an array) and also in a dictionary where I have the date as the key and every value is a array/list with persons that share the same birthday.

Then I do this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(); // Just some date
var personsFromList = personList.Where(person => person.Birthday == date);
var personsFromDictionary = dictionary[date];
```

If I run that 1000 times the Linq `.Where` lookup will be significantly faster in the end than the dictionary. Why is that? It does not seem logical to me. Is the results being cached (and used again) behind the scenes?

Comment: .Where doesn't loop through the list yet, it just prepares an iterator. Add a .ToList() or .First() for a better comparison

Comment: Lambda expression will get evaluated only when you do e.g .ToList(). See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794555/how-to-force-my-lambda-expressions-to-evaluate-early-fix-lambda-expression-weir

Comment: What do you mean?

`int[] array = new int[] { 4, 6, 8, 4, 9 };
IEnumerable<int> fours = array.Where(x => x == 4);

fours.Count(); // 2 elements`

When I do that the results are stored in the variable "fours"?

Comment: the `fours.Count()` is the one iterating over the `IEnumerable` that was prepared by the `.Where()` call

Answer (score 1):

From [Introduction to LINQ Queries (C#) (The Query)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries#query)

> ... the important point is that in LINQ, the query variable itself takes no action and returns no data. It just stores the information that is required to produce the results when the query is executed at some later point.

This is known as [deferred execution.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries#deferred-execution) (later down the same page):

> As stated previously, the query variable itself only stores the query commands. The actual execution of the query is deferred until you iterate over the query variable in a foreach statement. This concept is referred to as deferred execution...

Some linq methods must iterate the `IEnumerable` and therefor will execute immediately - methods like `Count`, `Max`, `Average` etc' - all the aggregation methods.

Another way to force immediate execution is to use `ToArray` or `ToList`, which will execute the query and store it's results in an array or list.